# Tangential Acceleration Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $$a = a_TT + a_NN = (\frac{d^2s}{dt^2})T + \kappa(\frac{ds}{dt})^2 N$$ prove that $$a_T = a \cdot T = \frac{a \cdot v}{||v||}$$
Where $a_T$ is tangential velocity, $a$ is an acceleration function, and $s$ is an arc length parametrization.
Where do I begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try computing $\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\vec{a}\cdot\vec{T}$, using your assumption that $\vec{a}=a_{\vec{T}}\vec{T}+a_{\vec{N}}\vec{N}$. You may find it helpful to recall that $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}=\lvert\vec{v}\rvert^2$ for any vector $\vec{v}$, and that the unit tangent vector $\vec{T}$ and the principal unit normal vector $\vec{N}$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 2):

Use the facts that ${\bf T}\cdot{\bf T}=1$ (why?), ${\bf T}\cdot{\bf N}=0$ (why?) and ${\bf T}=\frac{\bf v}{|{\bf v}|}$ (why?) and calculate ${\bf a}\cdot{\bf T}$.

Seems you don't even need to use the expressions with the arc length parameterization $s$.